# How to copy complete node from xml file and create multiple node by changing names of elements in Vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I want to copy complete node from xml file and creating new xml file with that node.

suppose that node consist of objects ...like button-1, Poygon-1...etc
I want to create multiple nodes by changing names to ....Button-2, Polygon-2..etc.
Like My node name is 
group name="GO_P_AIn1"
i want to create "GO_P_AIn2", "GO_P_AIn3", "GO_P_AIn3"
I want to create function in VB.net ...that every time it takes node as input and creates number of nodes in output xml file using same node, just by changing names of objects.

```
<group name="GO_P_AIn1" visible="true" wallpaper="false" toolTipText="/*S:0 {#102.Cfg_Tag}*/: /*S:0 #102.Cfg_Desc*/" exposeToVba="notExposed" isReferenceObject="true" linkSize="true" linkConnections="true" linkAnimations="linkWithExpression" linkBaseObject="(RA-BAS) P_AIn Graphics Library.GO_P_AIn" linkToolTipText="true">
    <rectangle name="AIN_AlarmPolygon1" height="41" width="146" left="500" top="168" visible="true" toolTipText="" exposeToVba="notExposed" isReferenceObject="true" linkSize="true" linkConnections="true" linkAnimations="linkWithExpression" linkBaseObject="(RA-BAS) P_AIn Graphics Library.AIN_AlarmPolygon" linkToolTipText="true" backStyle="transparent" backColor="#E0E0E0" foreColor="black" lineStyle="solid" lineWidth="2" patternStyle="none" patternColor="black" endColor="white" gradientStop="50" gradientDirection="gradientDirectionHorizontal" gradientShadingStyle="gradientHorizontalFromRight">
    </rectangle>
    <button name="AIN_Button_Faceplate1" height="35" width="140" left="503" top="171" visible="true" toolTipText="" exposeToVba="notExposed" isReferenceObject="true" linkSize="true" linkConnections="true" linkAnimations="linkWithExpression" linkBaseObject="(RA-BAS) P_AIn Graphics Library.AIN_Button_Faceplate" linkToolTipText="true" style="3d" captureCursor="false" highlightOnFocus="true" tabIndex="6">
        <command pressAction="" repeatAction="" releaseAction="Display ($#102.Inf_Lib$) $#102.Inf_Type$-Faceplate /T{#102},{#103},&quot;#120&quot;,&quot;#121&quot;,{X} #120 #121" repeatRate="0.25"/>
        <up patternColor="black" patternStyle="none" backColor="#E0E0E0" backStyle="solid" foreColor="black" endColor="white" gradientStop="50" gradientDirection="gradientDirectionHorizontal" gradientShadingStyle="gradientHorizontalFromRight">
            <caption fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="8" bold="false" italic="false" underline="false" strikethrough="false" caption=""/>
            <imageSettings imageReference="noImage"/>
        </up>
        <down downSameAsUp="true" patternColor="black" patternStyle="none" backColor="#ECE9D8" backStyle="solid" foreColor="black" endColor="white" gradientStop="50" gradientDirection="gradientDirectionHorizontal" gradientShadingStyle="gradientHorizontalFromRight">
            <caption fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="8" bold="false" italic="false" underline="false" strikethrough="false" caption=""/>
            <imageSettings imageReference="noImage"/>
        </down>
        <ability showDisabledState="false" expression="" enabledWhenExpressionIsTrue="true" disabledImageType="useGrayscale"/>
        <confirm confirmAction="false" buttonSetting="okCancel" titleBar="true" titleBarText="Confirmation" windowPosition="Centered of screen">
            <caption fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="10" bold="false" italic="false" underline="false" strikethrough="false" caption="Are you sure you want to perform this action?"/>
            <imageSettings imageReference="noImage"/>
        </confirm>
    </button>
    <button name="AIN_Button_Quick1" height="35" width="140" left="503" top="171" visible="true" toolTipText="" exposeToVba="notExposed" isReferenceObject="true" linkSize="true" linkConnections="true" linkAnimations="linkWithExpression" linkBaseObject="(RA-BAS) P_AIn Graphics Library.AIN_Button_Quick" linkToolTipText="true" style="3d" captureCursor="false" highlightOnFocus="true" tabIndex="5">
        <command pressAction="" repeatAction="" releaseAction="Display ($#102.Inf_Lib$) $#102.Inf_Type$-Quick /T{#102},{#103},&quot;#120&quot;,&quot;#121&quot;,{X} #120 #121" repeatRate="0.25"/>
     </button>
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="#102" description="Object Tag (P_AIn, P_AInAdv, P_AInDual, or P_AInMulti)" value=" "/>
        <parameter name="#103" description="Path (include program scope if tag is a program scope tag)" value="[BOP]"/>
        <parameter name="#120" description="Additional display parameter (e.g. /X100 or /CC) (optional)" value="0"/>
        <parameter name="#121" description="Additional display parameter (e.g. /Y100) (optional)" value="0"/>
        <parameter name="#122" description="0 = Always show Faceplate;  1= Show Quick Display for users without Maintenance Access (Code C); 2 = Always Show Quick Display" value="0"/>
    </parameters>
</group>
```

Comment: You need to post a better example showing the data after the changes.  Don't include the child nodes like up/down/ability/confirm unless they are important.

Comment: Thanks, My requirement is ...i want to generate one xmi file containing number of nodes. Suppose ...Input xml node:
<group name="GO_P_AIn1" visible="true" wallpaper="false">
    <rectangle name="AIN_AlarmPolygon1" height="41" >
    </rectangle>
    <button name="AIN_Button_Quick1" height="35" width="140">  
    </button>
</group>
I want output like: 
<group name="GO_P_AIn2" visible="true" wallpaper="false">
    <rectangle name="AIN_AlarmPolygon2" height="41" >
    </rectangle>
    <button name="AIN_Button_Quick2" height="35" width="140">  
    </button>
</group>
n number of times

Answer (score 0):

There is unclear thing about your question.
Do you want to create one output xml file for each node generated ? or do you want to merge all of them into one output xml file?
I think you want to create separate xml file for each node.
Treat those xml file as a text file, you can just replace the string "GO_P_AIn1" into "GO_P_AIn" & something

This is how i will do it:

```
Dim n as Integer = 2 'The number to add
Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(XMLFilePath)
Dim output as System.IO.StreamWriter
Dim outputPath as String = XMLFilePath & n.ToString
Dim xmlContent As String = objReader.ReadToEnd
objReader.Close()
xmlContent.Replace("GO_P_AIn1", "GO_P_AIn" & n) 'Replace the content with desired number
output = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(outputPath)
output.Write(xmlContent)
output.Close()
```

Loop through the number of node you want to create, and that's pretty much what you need to do

Comment: Thanks, My requirement is ...i want to generate one xmi file containing number of nodes.

Comment: Thanks, My requirement is ...i want to generate one xmi file containing number of nodes. Suppose ...Input xml node:
<group name="GO_P_AIn1" visible="true" wallpaper="false">
    <rectangle name="AIN_AlarmPolygon1" height="41" >
    </rectangle>
    <button name="AIN_Button_Quick1" height="35" width="140">  
    </button>
</group>
I want output like: 
<group name="GO_P_AIn2" visible="true" wallpaper="false">
    <rectangle name="AIN_AlarmPolygon2" height="41" >
    </rectangle>
    <button name="AIN_Button_Quick2" height="35" width="140">  
    </button>
</group>
n number of times

Comment: Then just add those some more replace for all the string you want to make change. I guess there's no other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I would use XML Linq and Regex

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim xml As String = _
                "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & _
                "<root>" & _
                "<group name=""GO_P_AIn1"" visible=""true"" wallpaper=""false"">" & _
                  "<rectangle name=""AIN_AlarmPolygon1"" height=""41"" > </rectangle>" & _
                  "<button name=""AIN_Button_Quick1"" height=""35"" width=""140""> </button>" & _
                "</group>" & _
                "</root>"

        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml)
        Dim root As XElement = doc.Descendants("root").FirstOrDefault
        Dim group As XElement = doc.Descendants("group").FirstOrDefault()
        Dim groupString As String = group.ToString()

        For index = 2 To 10
            Dim newGroup As XElement = XElement.Parse(groupString)
            root.Add(newGroup)
            For Each item As XElement In newGroup.DescendantsAndSelf().Where(Function(x) Not x.Attribute("name") Is Nothing)
                Dim name As XAttribute = item.Attribute("name")
                Dim value As String = CType(name, String)
                Dim newValue As String = Regex.Replace(value, "\d+", index.ToString())
                name.Value = newValue
            Next item

        Next index

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thanks you its working....but sir how to append that node every time in new xml file?
and save new xml file.

Comment: To save results use group.WriteXml(filename).  I don't know what your mean by "append in new xml file".  Can you give more details?

Comment: After each index we are getting new node ....like GO_P_AIn1, GO_P_AIn2, GO_P_AIn3...etc......so that i have append new node every time .

Comment: Where is the input coming from?  How do you determine what the new index will be?  I can't just randomly add information to an object.

Comment: Actually i will provide one excel file as input ....it contains index and all other data.
Suppose my index is 10.....then i have to generate 10 node from 1-10.
and these nodes will be saved in new xml file....finally i need xml file which contains "n" no of nodes.